# How to use mongo database read operation?

Tags: android

I do not what is wrong is wrong with this syntax. I am using remote mongodb.[image]
[image]

Comment: Have a look at this.  http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-query-document/

Hope this helps

Comment: Okay Thank you so much. i will read it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using valid Java syntax. Try this.

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("email", email);
query.put("password", password);
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
```